# Using boost asio to prevent syn flood attacks

Tags: c++, security, networking, boost

Already using boost::asio for basic network connectivity and I'd like to know if there's any built-in or standard boost facility for mitigating SYN flood attacks; I could try to handle it at a higher level but it's such a common problem and best handled at the connection establishment layer that I figured that there must be a common approach - is there?

Comment: This isn't the C++ answer you are searching for, but if you are using Linux and want to mitigate SYN flood attacks, I recommend SYN cookies: http://cr.yp.to/syncookies.html

Comment: SYN cookies are certainly a good general flood attack mitigation but it would be great if they were directly supported in boost instead of having to add them separately, thanks ... N

Comment: I'm wondering now whether enabling syn cookies at the linux os layer (i.e. https://www.ndchost.com/wiki/server-administration/hardening-tcpip-syn-flood ) would mean that tcp connections managed by boost::asio would use them automatically.  ... N